# Insert data in the middle of any table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `Countries(ID,Code,Name,....)` table.here `ID` is a auto generated primary key column.

this are few rows:

```
{1,AD,Andorra};
{2,AG,Antigua and Barbuda};
{3,AI,Anguilla}
```

now the problem is I cant find a way to add a new country Code, say 'AH' in such a way that the  automatically the table become like..

```
{1,AD,Andorra} 
{2,AG,Antigua and Barbuda}
{3,AH,......}
{4,AI,Anguilla}
```

in other words I need sorted list by `ID` and `CODE`.Its ok if I need to change some ID values.
I have a clustered index on `ID`.

plz,plz suggest me a way...

Comment: Why do you need the `ID` column for sorting purposes at all? If you really need something different than the `Code` column you can add another column `SortIndex`.

Answer (score 4):

`ID` (as a standard primary key) is not intended for sorting purposes. You should not rely on it. I'd recommend you to add **SortIndex** field instead. Then in two easy queries like

```
UPDATE Countries set SortIndex = SortIndex+1 WHERE SortIndex>= [your index]
```

And

```
INSERT INTO Countries VALUES (...)
```

You will get what you need. Also please don't forget to add `ORDER BY SortIndex` in select query.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the PK value of an entity like this is likely to head for a world of pain. Once the ID has been assigned to a particular entity, it shouldn't change.

e.g. you have another table that has a FK to a country id. IN your example, those other rows that related to Anguilla would now relate to the country "AH" represents.

It sounds like you are interested in the alphabetical ordering of the country codes. So for sorting purposes you just need to `ORDER BY Code` - you shouldn't change the PK values to suit your required sort order

Answer (score 1):

Can you please explain why you want to do this? It makes no sense in my opinion. Maybe you should add a "SortOrder" column or something instead? If the ID is a part of some sort of business rule you should, if possible, change the design.

Edit: As already answered in a few other posts :)

Answer (score 0):

You can update the table before inserting the new record.

```
update Countries set id = id + 1 where id >= 3;
```

Then,

```
insert into Countries values (3,'AH','AH');
```

Comment: if you wish to do this don't forget to set identity insert on --> SET IDENTITY_INSERT Countries ON (but i would suggest to look at the other answers and take an other route)